# 'mysql.user' is not of type 'BASE TABLE' error

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I tried repairing the `mysql.user` table in `phpmyadmin`but this error message `'mysql.user' is not of type 'BASE TABLE'` showed up. I tried repairing said table due to warning error message of `"1034 - index for Db is Corrupt in MYSQL"` I received when creating a new user account in my newly created database under `Privileges`. This message doesn't seem to affect my web app as it still runs but I'm worried that this might lead to future problems in my future web dev endeavors.

I'm still new in web dev so I have no idea how to debug or understand such message. **What does that message mean and how do I fix it?** If it helps, I'm currently on `v8.0.9` on both `XAMPP and PHP`.

Future thanks!

Comment: That's true mysql.user is a view.. In what way do you think this is broken?